# What are Sai Mahavakyas?

Tags: teaching

Satya Sai baba has said many mahavakyas which if we implement in life love will blossom in our heart. What are they?

Comment: The tag "Sai" is to be used whn questions are about Shirdi Sai but your question is not about him but about another Sai

Comment: @Rickross if a new tag is made satya sai, then i will use that. Anyways both are same person. satya sai is avatar of shirdi sai, i think it is ok.

Comment: Yes a new tag will be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.The Proper Study of Mankind is Man**

Man is the basic unit of Mankind. So it follows that he should be the epitome of the ideals that mankind stands for. How can man epitomize mankind? By spontaneously revealing the divine qualities of Love, Compassion and forbearance in perfect harmony in his thought, word and deed. In other words he should be a perfect example of his species.

**2. Work is Worship, Duty is God**

Any work undertaken with dedication and selflessness ie, without any expectation of reward becomes worship when it is offered to the Lord as an offering. All work is God’s work. When one belongs to God how can his work belong to another? When one discharges his responsibility with a sense of commitment to one’s own Self – the God seated in every heart that performance becomes verily God.

**3.Fatherhood of God and Brotherhood of Man**

Humanity has to be seen as a single race. Just as a beautiful garland is made up of flowers of various hues size and fragrance strung together the human race is also made up of men and women of different complexion and languages. Again, just as a garland is strung together by one thread, which is common to all flowers, the human beings also have the same Atma or life force as the core. This obviously means that a common binds all humans on the face of earth bond and therefore are brothers, east or west, black or white. This common factor called Atma has its origin in Brahma or Brahman or God. Hence, the Fatherhood of God and the Brotherhood of Man.

**4.Hands in Society Heads in the Forest**

Here hands stand for service and head for mind of the humans. Service to society is the bounden duty of everyone. And such service (Seva) has to be done selflessly, without expectation of any gain or reward. In other words, it has to be done with complete detachment. If the hands are to be engaged in Seva in a spirit of detachment and disinterestedness the mind should be completely free from desires. Freedom from desires means cultivation of Vairagya (detachment). Forest stands for Vairagya and head for the mind, which has to be cleansed of desires that cause attachment and selfishness. When the mind is thus cleansed the individual can do any amount of Seva selflessly for the welfare of society.

**5.My Life is My Message**

Preaching is easy; but to practice the same is difficult. For this Bhagawan Baba refers to a Drill Master for example. While all other teachers only teach the Drill Master demonstrates also what he instructs the students. Man must put into practice what he professes himself first. Then only he has the right to advise others. Bhagawan Baba lives every syllable of what He preaches to His devotees from daybreak to dusk. So, such an ideal life becomes a practical lesson and therefore a deep-going Message to His followers who need only remember what He does throughout the day.

**6.Miracles are My visiting cards**

What is natural with the Miraculous is miracle for the ordinary. Man cannot easily identify or recognise Divinity as he is enveloped in Maya or ignorance. He has to be woken up and told of the Advent of an Avatar who has come for His upliftment. Hence just as many of us present our identity card or visiting card to a stranger the Lord has to draw our attention to the Superhuman Power of the Avatar so that we would listen to Him. It is like a call attention notice. Once the identity is established, He can convey His Message. But He has not to make any special effort for this, as what He does naturally and spontaneously will look miraculous to us.

**7.You cannot always oblige, but can speak obligingly**

This applies both to the material and the spiritual world. One cannot be in society without mutual help and societal obligations. But very often one may not able to extend help in solving the problems of a brother or a sister because of personal limitations. In such cases one must, without losing balance, explain the position in an understanding way so that the one in need will be able to appreciate it. Such a situation often occurs while undertaking Seva activities by the Sevadal. Where discipline does not permit you to comply with somebody’s seemingly genuine request, one has to convincingly explain the position in minimum words so that the other party will feel satisfied and properly attended. Soft, short and sensible talk satisfies everyone.

**8.Hands that serve are holier than lips that pray**

What is the use of spending long hours in prayers and meditation behind closed door when one’s neighbour is helplessly groaning in pain? Such prayers will certainly fail to be responded by the Lord. What is expected of a human being is to leave the prayers and rush to attend to the one in pain. It amounts to the God in you rushing to the help of the God in that person, since Manava Seva is Madhava Seva. That is how one should visualise God – the God in everyone. Wiping a tear or rendering help to alleviate the misery of a brother is much holier that reading the scriptures or repeating Vedic mantras as the former is a selfless act while the latter is a selfish one.

**9.The end of education is character; the end of knowledge is wisdom**

When the knowledge acquired by reading and studying is analysed and pondered upon it develops into wisdom, granting an inner vision. The same knowledge can be converted into skill by its practical application. For example, values are understood and stored in memory as knowledge, but when applied in daily life it becomes a skill in the service to society. And the spontaneity of their application brings refinement in an individual resulting in good character, which really is the end of education.

**10.Money comes and goes, Morality comes and grows**

Money is known for the evanescence. It appears and disappears like a cloud. It never stays with anyone for all times. Still it can easily ensnare man in its web, as without it one cannot exist. But enamored by its glow and the comfort it offers man thinks that it has come to stay. But like passing clouds it disappears leaving its possess or still under illusion as he tries to obtain it more and more by fair or unfair means. In direct contrast is morality. Once one begins to adhere to the moral principles they permeate his life in every field of activity. Every exercise of its application gives a boost to its luster and growth with the result morality becomes ingrained in its votary as a permanent asset.

**11.Help Ever Hurt Never**

This is the quintessence of the eighteen puranas authored by the great Vyasa. Every being is a spark of the Divine that accounts for the totality of this universe. Hence there is an unseen bond between human beings. So, helping another would mean helping oneself. It becomes the bounden duty of all to help each other. Conversely it is a sin to harm anyone. It amounts to harming oneself. ‘Paropakaraya Punyaya Papaya Parapeedanam’, it is said. That is, it is meritorious to help others, but it is a sin to harm anyone. Under no circumstances one should think of harming another – in thought, word and deed. Hurt is not inflicted only bodily; it can be by harsh words as well. The wound caused by words cannot be healed, as it remains etched in the mind forever. Hence, one should never hurt another even if one cannot offer any help.

**12.Love All Serve All**

Only when one loves all, one can serve all, i.e., offer service without any discrimination. One who loves you is bound to be loved in return normally. But what is important and expected of us is to love the one who does not love us. This needs the awareness that there is a bond between all of us and the dislike is only superficial and momentary. All are embodiments of the same Atma and hence related inseparably. It is this awareness that underlies the urge to offer selfless service to one and all without any consideration of separateness based on any distinction. Offering help to another amounts to serving oneself. Because, by doing so one is only relieving oneself of the pain or discomfort that has afflicted him at the sight of the suffering of the other. In fact, only the body sheaths are different, the core is one and the same.

**13.Life is a Game Play It**

Victory and defeat are the duality natural with any game and life is no exception. But as one takes it in a spirit of sportsmanship in the case of a game, in life too, the ups and downs should be welcomed with equanimity. But the possibility of victory can be worked up in the case of the game of life by selecting better and more powerful teammates. In life the fight is between the good six and the evil six. No doubt the evil six, namely, lust, anger, greed, attachment, pride, and jealousy are highly skilled ones. But, the good six, namely, truth, righteousness, peace, love, non-violence and sacrifice always have an edge over the opponents because of their inherent virtue. So, life can be steered to success provided our teammates are the good or the desirable six.

**14.Matru Devo Bhava, Pitru Devo Bhava, Acharya Devo Bhava**

These Vedic injunctions virtually provide the pillars of Indian Culture. Bharat considers mother as the first God to be revered, as she is the one whose care and sacrifice are responsible for our birth and growth. It is on the lap of the mother that one learns the alphabets and the basics of one’s conduct. It is she who teaches the child to walk and talk and the fundamentals of social life. Naturally she deserves the first place of reverence and adoration. She tells the child of its father, who, as provider of wherewithal for the family, occupies only second place in the hierarchy of veneration. The father in turn takes the child to the Guru or Preceptor who trains him in morals, ethics and the scriptures for a meaningful life. And it is the Guru who tells him about God and his relationship with the Almighty. So mother first, father next, preceptor later and God last and Ultimate - that is the order of reverence expected to be offered by everyone.

**15.Praying Hearts, Serving Hands**

Every human heart is a temple. And in the altar of the temple is seated the Lord, the source of Love Energy that sustains the individual. It is not love alone that is housed there. Compassion, patience and forbearance also find a place there. In fact, heart is the origin of these divine qualities that charge human feelings with a sense of sacrifice, prompted by which the hands go out into action of charity and help to alleviate the sufferings of our brethren. Wherever and whenever selfless service is offered a heart filled with compassion and love must be behind that service. And for the Lord seated therein their prayerful offerings are the unfading flowers of Love, Compassion, Forbearance and Sacrifice.

**16.Character is the Most Precious Gift of Education**

Bhagawan Baba repeatedly tell all His devotees in general and students in particular that ‘if wealth is lost nothing is lost; if health is lost something is lost; and if character is lost everything is lost.’ Character constitutes ninety per cent of a man’s personality whether it be in the field of social life or leadership. And it is the function of Education to bring refinement in an individual making all the facets of his personality shine providing him an impressive (not only physical) personality. Wherefrom can the shine come for a good personality? It is by the harmonious blend of the five human values that lie embedded in every individual. So the purpose of education is to bring out those sterling qualities that alone can gift good character – the hallmark of true education. Swami calls this process ‘edcuare’ i.e., an education that takes care of the innate basic qualities, which are divine in content but lying hidden in an individual. And that is the most precious gift of education.

**17.Example, Not Precept is the best Teaching Aid**

‘Example is better than Precept’ is an old adage that conveys more than what it looks to imply. While discussing pedagogy, Bhagawan Baba often mentions the example of a Drill Master who not only instructs but physically demonstrates also. If the teacher is an ideal person, fifty per cent of teaching can be presumed to have been done. The young students whose eyes and ears are wide open, observes their teacher from all angles – how he looks, how he behaves, not only in the class but even outside. This total impression makes a strong background for teaching. If the teacher maintains lofty ideals, his exhortation goes deep into the hearts and minds of the young ones. He will be adored and emulated. And, that exactly is the purpose of teaching. It is not to doll out what is written in the book that a teacher is meant for. He has to set an example before the young ones. In other words he has to be the embodiment of virtues rendering his designation.

(http://www.saibaba.ws/teachings/saimahavakyas.htm)

Comment: Welcome! Pure copy paste from blogs are not encouraged here on this site. We have to add some explanation along with it. They look to me as ordinary common teachings of  everyday for sansarik (materialistic) people.  Mahavakyas are of special category , they have their deep spiritual meaning. So you can edit your question and instead of Mahavakyas use the word teachings etc.

Comment: Here are some posts about Mahavakyas - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=mahavakyas+

Comment: Next time, will take care.. sorry these are mahavakyas as you can see from the url. I didn't write that word myself.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar No one has copyright over the word mahavakyas.