# What is the meaning of mahavakya and how was/is it used?

Tags: terminology, etymology

What is the meaning of mahavakya? What was/is it used for, I mean what is its importance? What does mahavakya convey? This is not specifically with respect to Advaita Vedanta, but in general whichever darshana or any school who used that term.

**Note: This is not a duplicate of any of the questions linked below.**

I am asking the usage of mahavakya in the past by different schools, not Advaita alone.

For eg:  Adi Shankaracharya uses mahavakya in a different sense in Sariraka Bhasya 1.3.33:

> न हि **महावाक्ये** ऽर्थप्रत्यायकेऽवान्तरवाक्यस्य पृथक्प्रत्यायकत्वमस्ति यथा
>   न सुरां पिबेत् इति नञ्वति वाक्ये पदत्रयसंबन्धात्सुरापानप्रतिषेध
>   एवैकोऽर्थोऽवगम्यते न पुनः सुरां पिबेदिति
>   पदद्वयसंबन्धात्सुरापानविधिरपीति।
>
> na hi **mahāvākye**'rthapratyāyake'vāntaravākyasya
>   pṛthakpratyāyakatvamasti yathā na surāṃ pibet iti nañvati vākye
>   padatrayasaṃbandhātsurāpānapratiṣedha evaiko'rtho'vagamyate na punaḥ
>   surāṃ pibediti padadvayasaṃbandhātsurāpānavidhirapīti।
>
> For in general any minor syntactical unity, which is included in a
>   more comprehensive syntactical unity conveying a certain meaning, does
>   not possess the power of expressing a separate meaning of its own.
>   Thus, for instance, we derive, from the combination of the three words
>   constituting the negative sentence, '(Do) not drink wine,' one meaning
>   only, i.e. a prohibition of drinking wine, and do not derive an
>   additional meaning, viz. an order to drink wine, from the combination
>   of the last two words, 'drink wine.'

**Here, the mahavakya is "(Do) not drink wine".**

Another example, Satya Sai or his disciples used the word mahavakya in another sense: [Satya Sai Mahavakyas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33780/what-are-sai-mahavakyas)

Thus, I am asking how mahavakyas have been used by different schools, what is the meaning they want to convey?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Mahavakyas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11896/what-are-mahavakyas)

Comment: Related question- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30195/15963

Comment: Related question- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/30105/15963

Comment: @HayagreevRam it is none of the above. It is not a duplicate.